# Updating TextView in First Activity according to changes in SecondActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, onresume

I have two activities:
ActivityOne
ActivityTwo

ActivityOne opens ActivityTwo

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne .this,ActivityTwo.class);  
startActivity(i);
```

ActivityTwo updates some value MyValue in SharedPrefences.
ActivityOne has some TextView field that shows the value of MyValue.

After I close the ActivityTwo I want ActivityOne IMMEDIATELY to update
the TextView according to the new value of MyValue (that was changed in ActivityTwo).

I tried to call to SharedPrefernces and update the TextView view in OnResume() function in ActivityOne,
but somehow it doesn't get called.

Any ideas?

Thank you

More Code:

ActivityTwo updating MyValue:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.sharedPrefencesForSettingsName,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("MyValue", unspecified.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}
```

ActivityOne updating TextView:

```
if (settings.getBoolean("MyValue", true)) {
    textViewMine.setText("SomeText");
```

Comment: post more related code.

Comment: Without seeing your code pf saving and retrieving the sharedpreference value, it hard to say where the problem occurring...so, post related code.

Comment: in `onResume()` and `onStop()` method, print the value of `MyValue` in `LogCat`...see what value it returns.

Comment: The value is correct, the problem is that the TextView doesn't update the value immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Android's [Coordinating activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities) documentation, `onStop()` method of `ActivityTwo` is executing after `onResume()` of `ActivityOne` and that's why you are not getting the updated value from `SharedPreference`.

Now to solve the problem, move those code snippet from `onStop()` method to `onPause()` method as follows...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.sharedPrefencesForSettingsName,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("MyValue", unspecified.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it from you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.

`onActivityResult()` will be called as soon as you return to the caller.

See [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) in the documentation.

Comment: After I change the TextView value in onActivityResult(), it still shows the old value. I think I need kind of "refresh" to the view. How can I do it?